# Batch apex email query

Tags: apex, email, batch, query

Leads that are older than 1 month with Approval Status ‘Rejected’ should be emailed in the form of an ‘excel file’ to the System Administrator predefined in custom setting and should then be deleted from Salesforce. 
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using batch class easily. There are some points you should be clear with.
1)Criteria of for fetching the record, accordingly you will build your query.
2)Fields you want to keep in you excel file, accordingly you will add those fields in the query.
3)What is defined in the custom setting User ids/Email ids.

Below code will help you to understand the creating and attaching the email attachment.

Thanks.

```
string Query = 'select id ,LastName, Lead_Origin__c, LeadSource,Status, Mobile_Custom__c ,Email ,  Country__c  from Lead where Status = Rejected AND createdDate < LAST_MONTH';
        list<Lead>leadlist = [select id ,LastName, Lead_Origin__c, LeadSource,Status, Mobile_Custom__c ,Email ,  Country__c  from Lead where /*Criteria*/];
        string header = 'LastName, Status , Origin, Source, Mobile ,Email , Country \n';
        string finalstr = header ;
        for(Integer i=0 ; i<leadlist.size() ; i++){
               string recordString = '"'+leadlist[i].LastName+'","'+leadlist[i].Status+'","'+leadlist[i].Lead_Origin__c+'","'+leadlist[i].LeadSource +'","'+leadlist[i].Mobile_Custom__c+'","'+leadlist[i].Email+'","'+leadlist[i].Country__c+'"\n';
               finalstr = finalstr +recordString;
        }
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);
        string csvname= 'Leads.csv';
        csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
        csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {/*fetch the toaddress from custom settings*/};
        String[] ccAddresses = new list<string> {/*fetch the ccaddress from custom settings*/};
        String subject ='Lead CSV';
        string body= 'Hello,\nFind attachment of rejected leads older than 1 month. '; 
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        email.setCcAddresses( ccAddresses );
        email.setPlainTextBody(body);
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

Comment: `escapeCsv()` string method is helpful here

Comment: Hi. I am new to salesforce. Can you give me the entire code? That would be of great help.